# Remote full reset (re-install) of a Raspberry

Tags: headless, script, bash, reset

I've had a Raspberry Pi now for some time. I did a lot of fun stuff with it. A lot of the fun stuff is still on there, and that's not always fun.

I *could* reset my Raspberry Pi by walking over to it, powering it down, remove the micro SD card, and install a fresh image on it.
But, from an IT viewpoint, that feels wrong.

**I was wondering if** I could achieve a (somewhat) complete reset by executing a set of commands (and later on making a script out of them)

**What I would like to know is**:
 - Is it possible at all?
 - What are the minimum steps required to get a clean install?
 - What optional things could be useful (stuff like overwriting the SD with zeroes)

**I'm asking this because** I think that once my raspberry bush expands, it would be useful to do this without needing physical access. I have a feeling this method would also be more or less applicable to other Linux distro's.

Comment: Do you have a Raspberry Pi 3 ? They can boot from network.

Comment: @flakeshake I'm looking for something to do a complete reset, not a network boot. I can reboot my server thousands of times (not a great server, i know) and it keeps on running the same services, provides the same content, ... But when I run (let's say execute server_reset.sh) a script, it goes back to initial installation settings, hard disk wiped, config gone, ...

Or am I misunderstanding the concept of a network boot?

Comment: @NickDewitte  There are but they are less of a "complete reset", and more reverting installed packages.  I have the bones of an answer but I am reluctant to suggest it because you need to be experienced in linux to achieve it.  I can't give step by step instructions.

Comment: @couling I'm looking for a reset that is not package-specific. Who knows what I did on a boring weekend a year ago :)

Comment: If you have installed your SO using NOOBS, you can follow these steps: [Forcing entering in NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106646/112682).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: doing this by remote is inadvisable especially if, like me, you happen to be 70+ miles from your remote pi.  It's a very long drive if you screw it up.  When you do this fir the first time, do it "remotely" while sitting right next to the pi.

Secondly: yes, this is possible but I've never done it and although I believe I could achieve it, I'm not going to give step by step instructions.

**The principle:**

The SD card for raspbian is already partitioned.

- It has the main OS partition (EXT4 formatted, mounted at `/`).
- It has the boot partition (FAT32 formatted, mounted at `/boot`).

What you could do is

1. Shrink your main OS partition using `resize2fs` and `fdisk`.  *This is a bad idea with the PI online.   But if you want to shoot yourself in your foot then see here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-resize-ext4-root-partition-live-without-umount*
2. add an extra "recovery" EXT4 partition using `fdisk`
3. Install a working OS (Raspbian) on the new partition as a sort of "recovery OS".
4. Reboot into the recovery OS by changing PARTUUID `/boot/cmdline.txt` and rebooting the pi.  You can get the PARTUUID of your partitions by typing `sudo blkid`
5. Wipe clean and re-install the main OS partition.
6. Change `/boot/cmdline.txt` back and reboot into your new fresh OS.  It's best to check `sudo blkid` before doing this, it may have changed.

**The Prep**

If you are simply planning to do this in future, then you will do steps 1, 2 and possibly 3 with the pi offline and just leave the recovery partition in place until you need it.

**Installing the OS (Steps 3 and 5)**

Normally you download an SD card image from the website (https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and just overwrite your entire disk... but that's no good because you must not overwrite your partition table.

The downloaded images will have the exact 2 partitions you started with, so you need to copy the OS partition from the image into whichever partition you want to install to.

So you can try this:

```
# Download the image file
wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite_latestq
unzip raspbian_lite_latestq

# Create a loopback device to let you treat the image as a disk
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 2017-11-29-raspbian-stretch-lite.img

# Map the image's partitions
sudo partprobe /dev/loop0

#  Completely overwrite one of your partitions with one from the image
#  MAKE SURE YOU DON'T HAVE THE PARTITION MOUNTED WHEN YOU OVERWRITE IT
sudo dd if=/dev/loop0p2 of=mmcblk0p2 status=progress
```

**The part of this I really can't help you with is skipping the first boot which usually does something different to simply booting the pi**

Comment: So, the gist of it is that I need an intermediate OS, preferrably on a different (physical) disk, so I can remove the old OS and install the new one? Also, I'm quite aware that doing this, even more so _experimenting_ with this is not a great idea when I'm unable to intervene physically :)

Comment: Yes. The problem is that to do anything remotely with it you need a running OS and overwriting a running OS will in most cases cause it to crash before you succeed.